# How to simulate a GET action and pass it to the same page without reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I'm making a site that gets data from a server (Names, with an autocomplete script), gathers it all up, then on submit is SUPPOSED to send the data gathered to the server to get a JSON string back for usage further down on the page.

However, said server does not have the last part and I need to simulate it. But I have no idea how.

Using HTML, JS, jQuery and *nothing* else.

So the question being, as the structure is there,

how do I get

```
<form action="Search" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="foo"/>
<input type="hidden" name="bar"/>
<input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

Where foo and bar will have values at the time of submit,

to end up as a JSON object containing foo, bar and some random data I just make up,

in the .js, on pressing submit, WITHOUT reloading the page. (That is, pressing submit just kicks in the script and gives the form data to it but nothing else)

Edit: Sorry, changed post to get. The server will when working, respond to GET with JSON.

Comment: What do you mean by "said server does not have the last part"?  Does the server accept POST requests and respond with JSON?  If not, what format does it respond in?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the point is that the app is only partially complete -- the OP is writing the client side piece without having the server side piece in place yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put whatever JS array/object you expect back from the server in `returnedData`:

```
$(function(){
    var handleNewData = function(data){
        alert('I got:\nfoo:'+data.foo+'\nbar:'+data.bar+'\nresults:'+data.results);
    };
    var reallySubmit = false;
    $('form').submit(function(evt){
        if (reallySubmit){
          $.get(this.action,$(this).serialize(),handleNewData,'json');
        }else{
            // Put whatever spoof data you want here.
            var returnedData = {
                foo:this.elements.foo.value,
                bar:this.elements.bar.value,
                results:["jim", "jam", "jamboree"]
            };
            handleNewData( returnedData );
            return evt.preventDefault();
        }
    }); 
});
```

See the working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/sQtkY/4/

**Edit**: Sorry, I forgot that jQuery will properly parse a JSON string for you if you pass the parameter. Updated the answer to show this; no need to `stringify` your spoof values.

**Edit 2**: OK, one more update to show you how to include form values as well as spoof data.

Comment: Satisfying, yes, but I do need to add fake data, not just pass the json

Comment: Well now it just shows "foo", "bar", "jim" instead. There's my point, I need the data from the input AND fake data in *one* object

Comment: @Meke You'd better show exactly what format you expect the JSON data to be returned from the server looking like.

Comment: It's a bit irrelevant how it looks as all I need to do is fake it. input fields will have values, that is all I have, I need to simulate it being sent and the json response should contain the values of the input fields AND added to that a few fake variables of my own.

Comment: @Meke OK, I've updated again showing real data and spoof data. I humbly suggest, however, that it _does_ make a difference what format it gets back. If you are trying to pretend that you are the server, and given that there are many different ways that the server could return the form+new data, then you should define what that is and mimic it exactly.

Comment: That satisfying, yes. I'll now spend some time understanding the process. Thank you for your help. :) (And it won't be used for any server interaction, it's only temporary to test out a few other functions=

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("form").submit(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // NOTE: the following would work when the server is ready
  //$.getJSON("http://whatever.com/endpoint.php", $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
  //  console.log(data);
  //});

  var fakeData = {
    whatever: "data",
    you: "need",
    foo: "value",
    bar: "value"
  };
  console.log(fakeData);

});
```

Make sure you have firebug open to see the console.log().

Comment: And how do I get foo and bar into the var?

Comment: This just sets foo and bar to "value" and not it's actual value from the input

Comment: replace "value" with $(this).find("input[name='foo']).val()

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("form").submit(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
$.post("http://whatever.com/post.php",$(this).serialize(), function(data){
alert(data);
});
});
```

Comment: That should create querystring-formatted data ("foo=blah&bar=blahblah") rather then json-formatted data ("{foo:blah,bar:blahblah}").